# How to make query in an NLP Api?

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I am Making an API in which I want help is how to make query?.

I can display result using `127.0.0.1:8000/Naturallanguageprocessing/`

It is getting All attributes that i included parts of speech,lemmatization etc.but i have to display in this way `127.0.0.1:8000/?q = "querytext"&all = 1`

It should display all parts of speech ,lemmatization etc. and if i call `127.0.0.1:8000/?q = "querytext" & partsofspeech = 1 & lemmatization = 1`.

It should display parts of speech and lemmatization.

Below is my views.py.

```
 from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,HttpResponse
 from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
 from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
 from django.http import JsonResponse
 from django.conf import settings
 from rest_framework.response import Response
 from django.views import View
 import json
 import spacy
 import pdb
 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
 @api_view(["POST"])
def Naturallanguageprocessing(requestdata):
    try:
       text = str(requestdata.body)
       stopwordsremoval = []
       partsofspeech= []
       nounphrases = []
       word_lemma = []
       tokenization = []
       nameentityrecognization = []
       for word in (nlp(text)):
           a = (word.is_stop, word.text)
           b = (word.text, word.pos_, word.tag_)
           d = (word.lemma_)
           e = (word.text)
           tokenization.append(e)
           word_lemma.append(d)
           stopwordsremoval.append(a)
           partsofspeech.append(b)
       for word in (nlp(text).noun_chunks):
           c = (word.text)
           nounphrases.append(c)
       for word in (nlp(text).ents):
           f = (word.text,word.label_)
           nameentityrecognization.append(f)
           output = {"stopwordremoval": stopwordsremoval,
                  "partsofspeech": partsofspeech,
                  "nounphrases" : nounphrases,                
                  "word_lemma":word_lemma,
                  "tokenization":tokenization,
                  "nameentityrecognization":nameentityrecognization
}              
    return JsonResponse(output,safe = False)
except ValueError as e:
    return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```